# What does というもの mean here?

Tags: grammar

> 古書店の店主であるこの老人は、相手が誰であろうと笑顔**というもの**をまったく見せない。

Am I missing some nuance here? What if I removed というもの? How would it change?

Answer (score 2):

This might work as a very rough translation.

"The old gentleman and purveyor of second hand books was unacquainted with that thing commonly known as a smile"

Comment: yeah i know, but how is it different, the nuance, im asking if it would change if i removed it

Comment: It sounds like he has a lot of things he shows to customers but a smile isn't one of them. So that he never smiles is something quite particular to this old man. It's the one thing he never shows. It defines him. He's not just a guy who never smiles. He's "the guy" who never smiles.

If you drop というもの then he's just a guy who doesn't smile at people.